# How to change size factors in singlecellexperiment object

Tags: r, seurat

I am trying to run an RNA velocity analysis using velociraptor in R. I want to run the following code:

```
velo.out <- scvelo(sce, subset.row=top.hvgs, assay.X="spliced")
```

I get the error message:

> Error in .local(x, ...) : size factors should be positive

How do I resolve this?

I have tried running this, as I found it on another forum, but it didn't make a difference when I tried the code:

```
sce <- sce[, colSums(logcounts(sce)) >0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-positive size factors often result from not properly filtering low-quality cells. You should reconsider your quality control steps. See *"Orchestrating Single-Cell Analysis with Bioconductor"* [Basics: Chapter 1 - Quality Control](http://bioconductor.org/books/3.16/OSCA.basic/quality-control.html).

Otherwise, the non-positive size factor cells can be dropped with:

```r
sce <- sce[, sizeFactors(sce) > 0]
```

But it would be far better to properly purge low-quality cells *prior* to size factor computation, so that non-positive values are avoided in the first place.